# How are glm::vec3 and glm::mat4 initialised?

Tags: c++, constructor, glm-math

This is about understanding the glm source. I wanted to know if glm does zero initialise its classes and tried it. Yes, `glm::vec3` and `glm::mat4` are initialized, even without providing a constructor value. Then I wanted to understand how it is done and read the source of [`glm::mat4`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00124_source.html#l00041) template.

There is this section:

```
...
enum ctor{null};

// Constructors
GLM_FUNC_DECL tmat4x4();
GLM_FUNC_DECL tmat4x4(tmat4x4 const & m);
GLM_FUNC_DECL explicit tmat4x4(ctor Null);
...
```

I can read there is a `(void)` constructor (ctor) but without definition, so no `{...}` section. And there is an `explicit` ctor with `0` as parameter coming from first element of type `enum ctor`, which of course gets index value `0`.

- Where are the constructor definitions? How can I find them?
- What is that explicit Null ctor for?
- How is `glm::mat4` initialised to an identity matrix when I just write: `glm::mat4 myMatrix;`

---

**Edit:** browsing the more current source files on GitHub brings one from `mat4x4.hpp` to `detail/type_mat4x4.hpp` which `#includes` the implementation details in [type_mat4x4.inl](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_mat4x4.inl). There the ctor behaviour gets visible.

Comment: you may use wrong tag, it should be [tag:glm-math]?

Comment: Thanks, changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it's under `"glm/detail/type_mat4x4.inl"`
- it's a constructor that does nothing, in *0.9.6.3* it becomes `enum ctor{uninitialize}`
- It calls the default constructor

---

BTW, I can't download your version, this answer is base on *0.9.6.3*

Comment: Google send me to old version of 9.2. I just updated to 9.8.3. GLM Manual PDF makes initialisation rules clear. GLM Code is understandable now too: ctor() implementation of :tmat4x4() easily shows initialisation `ifndef GLM_FORCE_NO_CTOR_INIT` ....

Comment: It seems that in version 0.9.8 it's still default initialized while in the master branch on GitHub it's not the case anymore.

Answer (score 6):

It's not inialized by default anymore. Define GLM_FORCE_CTOR_INIT before your includes to force the initialization.
https://github.com/g-truc/glm/issues/809

```
#define GLM_FORCE_CTOR_INIT
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
glm::mat4x4 view{ 2 / (right - left), 0, 0, 0,
            0, 2 / (top - bottom), 0, 0,
            0, 0, -2 / (farplane - nearplane), 0,
            -((right + left) / (right - left)), -((top + bottom) / (top - bottom)), -((farplane + nearplane) / (farplane - nearplane)), 1
        };


glm::mat4 view{ 2 / (right - left), 0, 0, 0,
            0, 2 / (top - bottom), 0, 0,
            0, 0, -2 / (farplane - nearplane), 0,
            -((right + left) / (right - left)), -((top + bottom) / (top - bottom)), -((farplane + nearplane) / (farplane - nearplane)), 1
        };

glm::uvec4 ViewPort(0,0,0,0);

glm::vec3 Origin(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```